# Teamcity command line build step dnscmd is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: command-line, dns, teamcity

If I remote onto the server as the Teamcity service account and try to run dnscmd from c:/ it works fine. Teamcity attempting to run it results in

> 'dnscmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I can run other exe's that reside alongside dnscmd in c:/windows/system32, just not dnscmd it seems.